# ¿Como llamar una accion de un controlador desde el Layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un navbar en mi layout, y mi idea es mostrar un numero que es la cantidad de envios (Modelo) qe se hicieron. El tema es que no se como puedo llamar desde mi Layout esa accion.

Muchas gracias!!

**SharedFold**

```
        public class SharedController : Controller
        {
            public ApplicaAccContextDB db = new ApplicaAccContextDB();

            public ActionResult _EnviosPendientes()
            {
               return PartialView("_EnviosPendientes", db.Envios.ToList());
            }
        }
```

(Vista parcial) **_EnviosPendientes:**

```
  @model IEnumerable<ApplicaAccWeb.Models.EnviosFold.Envios>

  @{ 
      int i = 0;
  }

  @foreach (var item in Model) {
      if (item.Estado == false)
      {
          i++;
      }
  }

  @i
```

**_Layout:**

```
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse collapser pull-right">

                <!--Tabla con botones mas inicios-->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" style="padding-right:15px">
                    <li style="padding:8px">
                        <button onclick="location='../Envios/EnviosPendientesLista/'" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger">
                            Envios <span class="badge">@Html.Partial("_EnviosPendientes")</span>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li style="padding:8px">
                        @*Obtener ID de usuario y pasarlo por parametros*@
                        <button onclick="location='SharedFold/MensajesLista/'+3"  class="btn btn-warning" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                            Mensajes <span class="badge"></span>
                        </button>    
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

Comment: Que has intendado?

Comment: Cree una vista parcial y la llamaba desde el navbar. Pero solo me funciona en el Index, ya si cambio de vista me tira un error en el layout. La verdad? No se como hacerlo

Comment: Hola Joaquín, bienvenido a [es.so], para saber exactamente el problema que intentas solucionar es necesario que edites tu pregunta (el link aparece en la parte inferior izquierda de tu pregunta) con segmentos de código, esto nos dará una visión más detallada del error o problématica que presentas, así mismo, tu pregunta será más interesante y obtendrá mayor atención. Saludos :)

Comment: Listo, ya lo hice. Muchas gracias @Flxtr esperemos que respondan con la solución :)

Comment: @JoaquinFerrari yo te podría ayudar :) sin embargo requiero de más detalles, por ejemplo, ¿exactamente en qué parte deseas mandar llamar a la acción del controlador? ¿cuál es el objetivo de mandar llamar a un controller en tu layout?

Comment: La quiero llamar desde el Layout, en el primer boton, donde estoy llamando a la vista parcial que dice: @Html.Partial("_EnviosPendientes"), que en si la vista parcial devuelvo un numero que es la cantidad de envios con estado false, se entiende?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedo probarlo por ahora, pero la primera solución que se me ocurre es hacer uso de la [colección `Items` del contexto actual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.httpcontext.items(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class SharedController : Controller
{
    public ApplicaAccContextDB db;

    public SharedController()
    {
        db = new ApplicaAccContextDB();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["EnviosPendientes"] = db.Envios.ToList();
    }

    ...
}
```

y lo uses en el Layout de la siguiente manera:

```
@Html.Partial("_EnviosPendientes", (List<ApplicaAccWeb.Models.EnviosFold.Envios>)Context.Items["EnviosPendientes"])
```

---

**EDIT**

De acuerdo a tu comentario, entonces mejor inténtalo con [secciones](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/721055/asp-net-mvc-layout-and-section-in-razor):

- En el `_Layout.cshtml`

  ```
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse collapser pull-right">

      <!--Tabla con botones mas inicios-->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" style="padding-right:15px">
          <!-- Ojo: aquí es donde ocurre la magia -->
          @RenderSection("ViewData", required: false)
          <li style="padding:8px">
              @*Obtener ID de usuario y pasarlo por parametros*@
              <button onclick="location='SharedFold/MensajesLista/'+3" class="btn btn-warning" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                  Mensajes <span class="badge"></span>
              </button>
          </li>
          <li>
              @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  ```
- En tu controlador/acción:

  ```
  public ActionResult Envios()
  {
      ...
      ViewBag.EnviosPendientes = db.Envios.ToList();
      return View();
      // O
      ViewData["EnviosPendientes"] = db.Envios.ToList();
      return View();
      // O
      return View(db.Envios.ToList());
  }
  ```
- En la vista:

  ```
  @* Depende de cómo lo mandes, si usas un *@
  @model IEnumerable<ApplicaAccWeb.Models.EnviosFold.Envios>
  @* Tu contenido *@
  @section ViewData{
      @{
          int i = 0;
          // O lo obtienes con
          var _lista = (List<ApplicaAccWeb.Models.EnviosFold.Envios>)ViewBag.EnviosPendientes;
          // O
          var _lista = (List<ApplicaAccWeb.Models.EnviosFold.Envios>)ViewData["EnviosPendientes"];

          foreach (var item in _lista)
          {
              if (!item.Estado)
              {
                  i++;
              }
          }
      }
          <li style="padding:8px">
              <a href="../Envios/EnviosPendientesLista/" target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger">
                  Envios <span class="badge">@i</span>
              </a>
          </li>
  }
  ```

Y así, en cada vista adaptas la sección `ViewData` conforme a las necesidades de cada vista, la cual puedes incluir o no en el Layout.

Comment: Funciona. El tema es que si cambio de vista, me pide el modelo de la vista que me encuentro. En este caso trabajamos con Envios, pero si paso para una vista de clientes me pide el modelo clientes. Me explico? Muy buen metodo igual!!!

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta, chécala.

Comment: No me esta mostrando nada en la vista al ejecutarlo, como que no me lee la PartialView :(

Comment: Olvídate por el momento de las PartialView, alguna vez, iniciando, intenté hacer algo similar pero nunca me ejecutó el código del controlador, por eso te digo que mejor uses secciones, o mejor dicho, no uses PartialView para ello y reemplázala por una Section. Cada Section depende de la vista que estés usando por lo que las puedes personalizar para cada una sin crear acciones adicionales ni montones de PartialView. Las PartialView utilízalas cuando sean de propósito general y reutilizables (que no es el caso que planteas).

Comment: Perfecto. Entiendo, pero la accion Envios() del controlador, donde la estas llamando?

Comment: Entiendo lo que haces, es buen metodo. Pero acordate que en cada vista que viajo ya esta recibiendo un modelo. Por ejemplo: Si viajo a la vista de clientes ya tengo un modelo Clientes, y no se puede recibir 2 modelos en la misma vista.

Comment: Ese es un ejemplo, no sé cómo se llame tu ActionResult, pero el chiste es que desde la acción que invoca a la vista establezcas ese `db.Envios.ToList()` y lo mandes a la vista, sea que lo mandes como el modelo o en el objeto `ViewBag` o en el objeto `ViewData`; esos códigos te los puse como ejemplo.

Comment: Puedes mandar información adicional a la vista a través de `ViewBag` o de `ViewData` (incluso puedes incluir ambos a la vez, no hay ningún problema); checa esta página: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/viewdata-viewbag-and-tempdata-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Perfecto. Muchisimas gracias de verdad! Como hago para calificarte?

Comment: Al lado izquierdo de mi respuesta hay un número grande que son los votos y justo debajo hay una palomita, dale clic para marcar la respuesta y me alegra que te haya funcionado!

Comment: Listo. Te llego?

Comment: Sin problemas ;) Gracias por la calificación!